# Flashing White Lines with NVidia 940m in 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, graphics, gpu, hybrid-graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 along side Windows 10 on my ASUS K501L laptop. It has a Nvidia GeForce 940M and an Intel graphics chipset. I've been having flashing white lines every few seconds across the screen. I've noticed that if I increased the brightness the lines also appear more often.

Ubuntu: 16.04
Hardware: Asus K501L
GPU: NVidia 940m

Comment: Which driver are you using?